# Передать список файлов в функцию

Tags: c#, файлы

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

}

public static string [] GetFiles()
{
    string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\code\\", "*.xml");

    return filePath;
}

public static void ParseFile(string fname)  
{
    // Тут делаем что-то
}
```

Вопрос просто детский. Однако я что-то затупил. Мне нужно получить список файлов из папки, после чего обработать все файлы функцией `ParseFile`. Как это сделать? Я понимаю, что куда-то `foreach` нужно воткнуть, но не пойму куда и с какими аргументами.

Спасибо.

Comment: ну напишите еще одну функцию, например. Которая будет прогонять в foreach'e ваши пути к файлам и что-то с ними делать

скажем, так: 

    void Perfom(IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        foreach(var fileName in files) 
        {
             ParseFile(fileName);
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\code\\", "*.xml").ToList().ForEach(x=>ParseFile(x));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, лучше работайте с List, чем с массивами в шарпе. То есть, перепишите вашу функцию `GetFiles`:

```
public List<string> GetFiles()
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\code\\", "*.xml").ToList<string>();
}
```

А в мэйне что-то типа:

```
foreach(string file in GetFiles())
{
    ParseFile(file);
}
```